# Forward declaration of a class in a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

How can i forward declare a class in a namespace. For example below is a header file of a library and user dont need to know about private myPtr so dont need to include boost headers when include below header file. So how can I forward declare the boost::shared_ptr to enable user code compilation?

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass
{

private:

  boost::shared_ptr<Mytype> myPtr;

}
```

Comment: @JaredC Not if he provides a pre-compiled library.

Comment: @korhan I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but it sounds like it might be similar to one I asked recently - have a look at the answers here and see if any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978775/how-to-avoid-include-dependency-to-external-library

Comment: You're trying to alleviate the consumer of this little gem from having to include the boost headers to get the definition of something you'd rather they didn't know about in the first place; does that about sum it up?

Comment: @Jon thx for the replay , I just checked it, but my problem is with forward declaring a class within a namespace that consumer dont know about(or dont need to know aobut for me.)

Comment: @WhozCraig yes thats what i am try to do. By the way my library is a static library if it changes anything

Comment: If that is the case, you'll be abstracting to a generic declarative form that is not boost-specific in your header, and providing an implementation in your lib-code .cpp file(s) that is. Not the prettiest thing, but ultimately needed if you don't want peeps to see under the covers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** The inclusion of `<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>` is required here. No (intelligent) way around it. `MyType` itself can be forward-declared though.

Of course, you can just write `#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>` at the top of your header so your users don't have to do it themselves. It's actually good practice to provide *autonomous* headers (ie headers that can be included first without errors).

---

The rules about forward compilation are slightly complicated. It is easier to understand the reason about them than to try and memorize all the cases.

There are two factors:

- semantics
- memory attributes (size & alignment)

*Semantics*: in order to access the objects' methods, attributes or base classes, you need to know about them. Seems obvious, of course, except that the constructors, assignment operators and destructors, even when automatically generated, are methods. It is easy to forget about them.

*Memory attributes*: unlike most languages, C++ tries to be as efficient as possible, which means that it will allocate memory for the object *right there* rather than allocate it somewhere and just use a pointer at the point of use, unless you instruct it to do so of course (by using either *pointer* or *reference*). In order to know how much to allocate, the compiler needs to see the *guts* of the object, ie what's underneath the hood. This means that even though the exact details are not accessible (`private`/`protected` stuff) they need be visible so it can see that 24 bytes aligned on a 8-bytes boundary are required (not relevant to `shared_ptr` by the way).

In the Standard we say the object's *definition* is required for either of those two needs (methods and memory layout). If the definition is required, then it must be available obviously.

---

Okay, now that we know the reasons, we can check various things. Is a definition needed when:

- using an object as argument to `sizeof` or `alignof`? **yes** (obviously, memory attributes required)
- using an object as attribute? **yes** (memory attributes required)
- using an object as static attribute? **no** (1)
- using a pointer or reference to an object as attribute? **no** (2)
- using an object as an argument in a function declaration? **no** (3)
- using an object as a return type in a function declaration? **no** (3)
- passing a pointer or reference to an object around? **no** (4)
- casting to base class? **yes** (semantic check of presence & accessibility of base class)
- converting to another type? *depends* (5)

(1) the declaration does not require anything, however the definition of the static attribute will require the object's definition.

(2) a pointer is either 32 bits or 64 bits large (depending on how you compile, ...) independently of the object. A reference has an implementation-defined representation.

(3) even if taken/returned by value! It may be required for the function definition (if used within) or the function call site though.

(4) of course, should you try to use it (`p->foo()` or `p.foo()`) then it's another story.

(5) if you need to use the object's conversion operators, then it's required obviously; otherwise if you use a constructor of the other type then the same rules as for functions apply (the other type definition is required though).

I hope things are clearer now.